# Where are Eclipse configuration options documented?

Tags: java, eclipse

In trying to troubleshoot a configuration.ini issue, I ran into where I didn't have the osgi.bundlefile.limit value set high enough for the application we are using. What puzzled me is looking at the Eclipse documentation, I see where they are using: 
-D
and
-X 
in front of various settings, yet I cannot find in the Eclipse documentation what -D or -X mean. Anybody know what they mean or even where they are documented?

Comment: Show us an example of the -X prefix.

Comment: The -X actually aren't in the config.ini file, and are related to the java memory size: -Xms256m and -Xmx1024m. Still would like to know where their secret decoder ring is, I recognize I need to use the -X for those settings, but it would be nice to know what that flag means.

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Farguments.htm
These are some documented on the eclipse website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Java configuration options rather than Eclipse see for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

`-D` defines a system property - `-Dproperty=value`

`-Xmx1024m` is the Java option to set the maximum heap size.

Eclipse doesn't know anything about what these options are it just passes them to the Java command used to run the application.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find them *anywhere* in the Eclipse docs! Thanks.